# Stack implementation without using pointers

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I need to implement a very basic stack data structure for keeping integers in `C` without using pointers. Is this possible using only arrays? Simple pseudo code would be highly appreciated.

Edit: I'm using a model checking tool called [UPPAAL](http://www.uppaal.org/) that supports the basic functionalities of `C` and I need to use a recursive function which `UPPAAL` doesn't support. I thought about implementing the recursion using my own stack because `UPPAAL` doesn't support pointers. Any better ideas?

Comment: Are you allowed to needlessly waste stack memory?

Comment: Why are you allowed to use arrays but not pointers? They are fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: Is the restriction against pointers a restriction of the assignment or because you are unsure about using them yourself?

Comment: Smells like homework to me.  I can't imagine another scenario which would disallow the use of pointers.

Comment: Is this homework? If so you might want to add the homework tag.

Comment: @Chimera its not a homework..I have already done the hard part...algorithm..model design etc. Im just tackling with the environment limitations!!!!

Comment: @EdS. its not a homework..I have already done the hard part...algorithm..model design etc. Im just tackling with the environment limitations!!!!

Comment: @Dataknife because I can't...explained in the Edit

Comment: @KendallFrey explined in the Edit

Comment: @chris if I have no other option YES!

Comment: Then why do you have a "no pointer" requirement?  That doesn't seem... sane... in the context of non-academic code.

Comment: @SabaAhang, Then I don't see any other problem with just making an array that's your maximum allowed number of elements and keeping track of how much is filled.

Comment: So to be clear, it's not a restriction on the actual language but of the verification tool that you're using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're allowed to make one dynamic allocation for the entire structure (which you must, one way or another), you can just use *integers* for an offset:

```
unsigned int capacity = 100;
unsigned int top      = 0;

int * buf = malloc(sizeof(int) * capacity);

// push:
buf[top++] = n;

// pop:
int value = buf[--top];

// empty:
int is_empty = (top == 0);

// increase capacity:
if (top == capacity)
{
    int * tmp = realloc(buf, capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));
    if (!tmp) { /* out of memory, die */ }
    buf = tmp;
    capacity *= 2;
}

// destroy
free(buf);
```

This code is just for exposition; in your implementation you would obviously check for overflow and underflow.

Comment: push execute `buf[top++]=n`, after pop execute `value=buf[top--]`  value is not n, value is undefined!